# Leaving SQL Management open on the internet

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows, security

I am a developer, but every so often need access to our production database -- yeah, poor practice, but anyway... My boss doesn't want me directly on the box using RDP, and so we decided to just permit MS SQL Management Console access so that I can do my tasks. So right now we have the SQL box somewhat accessible on the internet (on port 1433 if I am not mistaken), which opens a security hole. But I am wondering, how much of an uncommon practice is this, and what defaults should I be concerned about? We use MSSQL2008 and I created an account that has Read-Only access, because my production tasks only need that. I didn't see any unusual default accounts with default passwords on the system, so I would be interested to hear your take. (And of-course, is there a better way?)

Comment: pls don't open your sql server publicly across the internet!  Use a VPN!

Comment: You are correct that exposing SQL Server is a significant security hole.  Instead, establish a secure VPN to your production environment and use SSMS through that tunnel.

Comment: Any difference from running RDP publicly, or is this also a no-no? Or rather, are we increasing risk by running all on VPN, and then getting screwed if it stops working?

Comment: We don't expose RDP in our prod environment either.  It has to go through the VPN.

Comment: The risk of "VPN goes down and we're screwed" is negligible, esp. in proportion to the risk of "someone hacks into the DB server and we're screwed".

Answer (score 2):

Exposing a database or RDP directly to the Internet, even if locked down, is akin to putting up a sign saying "do not enter" -  the security provided is not significant (and more importantly, could disappear tomorrow when an exploit is discovered).

A VPN is akin to actually locking the door - although security holes are sometimes discovered in VPN software, they are much rarer, as security is a primary concern there (as opposed to e.g. database servers, where it's mostly an afterthought). As for stability, I've never encountered this problem with a VPN server under such a small load (occasional access by a few users).

Bottom line: Unless you need to expose it to everyone (e.g. a web server), don't put it directly on the Internet.

BTW, are you sure your database server has not been hacked? In my experience, it means "didn't notice it", or at best "not hacked yet" - either way, that's a far cry from "reasonably secure".